# How return value in specific field with same class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have field with same class but different value I know there is a way to send value with $(this) in jquery but when returning the function result I want to update the specific field that has been clicked ? How I can do this $(this) is changing every field with the same class.

Class is auto generated in loop and I don't want to use different classes for every field.

There must be a way I am missing to achieve this

Here is my code.

```
$(".voteclick").click(function () {
var dynname = $(this).attr('name');
var votevalue = $(this).next().val();
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost/wpcomnt/wp-content/themes/smart-mag-child/subrating.php',
    type:"POST",
    data:"dynname=" + dynname + "&" + dynname + "=" + votevalue + "&measure=" + $('#measure').val(),
    dataType:'json',
    success:function (mydata) {
        if(votevalue == 'up') {

            $(this).val('Agree: ' + mydata); // this must not change every .voteclick field it should change only the clicked one ?

        }
        else if(votevalue == 'down') {
            $(this).val('Disagree: ' + mydata); // this must not change every .voteclick field it should change only the clicked one ?

        }
        //$(".voteclick").val('Agree: '+mydata);
    },
    error:function () {
        $(".errormainbtn").slideDown();
    }
 });
});
```

Please read the comment next to this line `$(this).val('Disagree: '+mydata);`

there are many field's they are changed once I click it because the class is same, and auto generated please tell me a way by which I can change only the field I clicked the class is

```
 ".votelick"
```

Comment: Inside ajax success callback, `this` is referring to jqXHR object. You should set `context: this,` as option of `$.ajax()` method, check the DOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wolff mentioned, you need to set `context:this` in the options for the ajax call. By default, in the success function, `$(this)` refers to the  jqXHR object. If your ajax call is in an event handler, and you set `context:this`, `$(this)` in the success function will instead refer to the element that triggered the handler.

Here's a [working example](http://affordable-glass.com/test/ajaxtest.html)

```
$(".voteclick").click(function () {
    var dynname = $(this).attr('name');
    var votevalue ='up';//changed for example
    $.ajax({
        url:'test.php',//changed for example
        type:"POST",
        context:this, //this is the line you need to add
        data:"dynname=" + dynname + "&" + dynname + "=" + votevalue + "&measure=" + $('#measure').val(),
        dataType:'text', //changed from 'json' for my example
        success:function (mydata) {
           if(votevalue == 'up') {
                $(this).val('Agree: ' + mydata); 
            }
            else if(votevalue == 'down') {
                $(this).val('Disagree: ' + mydata); 
            }
        },
        error:function () {
            $(".errormainbtn").slideDown();
        }
     });
});
```